# wireguard installation: modprobe wireguard fails

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard, kernel-module

I installed wireguard on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and all is fine.
On another older machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I have problems in wireguard installation. When I execute

```
  sudo ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
```

It displays:

```
  RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I researched and found that the kernel module for wireguard is not loaded, as:

```
  sudo modprobe wireguard
```

displays:

```
  modprobe: FATAL: Module wireguard not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic
```

However,

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/dkms status
```

displays:

```
 wireguard, 1.0.20201112: added
```

I also found that there was a possibility that the wireguard kernel module was not getting loaded because of the secure boot feature but I am not using UEFI for boot.
Any suggestions would be welcomed. I have tried the usual suspects: apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, etc. but to no avail. How do I get the wireguard kernel module to load?

Answer (score 0):

added is not the same as installed.  I would run the dkms build and dkms install commands again.

Comment: Tried but that did not help.